# Visualizing Raycaster

Tags: three.js, raycasting

I am trying to detect an intersection by using a raycast. My current problem is that I am not sure about my raycast aiming into the desired direction. So my general question is: Is there a way to make a raycast visible? And if so: How is it done? This would help me a lot.

Michael

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why dont you draw a line from your origin to the direction of the ray.

To be more specific (using r83):

```
    // Draw a line from pointA in the given direction at distance 100
    var pointA = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 );
    var direction = new THREE.Vector3( 10, 0, 0 );
    direction.normalize();

    var distance = 100; // at what distance to determine pointB

    var pointB = new THREE.Vector3();
    pointB.addVectors ( pointA, direction.multiplyScalar( distance ) );

    var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    geometry.vertices.push( pointA );
    geometry.vertices.push( pointB );
    var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color : 0xff0000 } );
    var line = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );
    scene.add( line );
```

Codepen at: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/evNqGy

Comment: That's what I did in the end. I just hoped there was a convenient way of setting some visibility flag without additional programming.

Thank you!

Comment: Any tips on how you did that? I'm new to threejs so "drawing a line from your origin to the direction of the ray" isn't a piece of cake for me :)

Comment: Please explain further on how to draw a line or something...thanks

Comment: Big thankx brother :) For me the codePen demo only works when I change library to r84 but thats ok I understand the basics.

Answer (score 11):

Here is another method to show your raycsters:

```
scene.add(new THREE.ArrowHelper(raycaster.ray.direction, raycaster.ray.origin, 300, 0xff0000) );
```